# The big !important; troubles

Tags: html, css

I still dont get it, which color will be paragraph "test1" and why?

```
<style>
  p {
    color: red; 
    font-style: italic;
  }
</style>

<div style="color: green;!important">
  <p style="color: blue;">test1</p>
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importance does not cascade.

Even if a parent element (the `<div>`) has an `!important` property (note that it actually doesn't, due to a syntax error), it will still be overridden by any property applied to the child element.

`!important` can only override other rules that are applied to the *same* element.

Therefore, the first `<p>` will be blue, since there is nothing to override its inline style.

Comment: Thank you, didnt know that !important isn't cascading.

Answer (score 3):

> which color will be paragraph "test1" and why?

**Blue**. Even with your typo, it would still be blue. The `color: green !important` style only applies to text within the `div`. Therefore the *inline* style of `color: blue;` is the most *specific*.

See the differences in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PyNW/).

I encourage you to learn about [how CSS specificity works](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 0):

It will be blue, because it has a style attribute making it blue.  The div says green, but you have the `!important` flag after the semicolon.  But even if you had a space instead of a semicolon, the style attribute would override it.  It will be blue.